# Merge cells with same value ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I'm currently working on exporting my project to excel. It exports it as I want, but when I try to merge cells, I'm unable to do it.

Here's what I want my outcome to look like :

[image: Outcome]

Here's my code :

```
 void merge()
            {

                int lastrow = ws.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
                for(int i = 15; i <= lastrow; i++)
                {
                    string a = ws.Cell(i, 3).Value.ToString().Trim();
                    string b = ws.Cell(i - 1, 3).Value.ToString().Trim();
                    if (a==b )
                    {
                        var range = ws.Range($"C{i-1}:C{i}");

                        range.Merge();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I know the issue is with  `ws.Range($"C{i-1}:C{i}");` from another post, but the user who gave the answer gave no hint or clue as to where to start.